# Is it necessary to upgrade facebook php sdk from version 3.2.3 to 4.0.0

Tags: php, facebook

With facebook php sdk 4.0.0 code structure changed. if i use old versions will it be a problem for my next projects. Is there a possibility that old versions will not work after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project, you should always use the newest frameworks (SDKs) available unless you have a good reason for not doing so. A good reason for not updating is if the SDK requires new software (which often requires better hardware, especially in the mobile app business), but this is only interesting for apps/programs that aren't web based. Updating server software is often much more easier than making hundreds of user replace their PC/mobile device).

Most SDKs receive bug fixes even though there are deprecated in case they're used by many other projects. Normally, old SDKs should work for at least a couple of years (and I don't think Facebook is going to do it differently unless they announced it on their blog, and or the docs. You should definitely check these out!). However, if you want to update a project   that uses deprecated/old SDKs (in a regular base), you should also upgrade the SDKs because it will most likely provide new features that might become essential in the future.   Sometimes the framework (SDK) even offers scripts that help you do so. (For instance, if you want to update from Python 2 to Python 3, there are a lot of scripts that make it very easy. There might even be a script that tells you what to update).

In your case, I wouldn't update the SDK for your old project (unless you need to always have the new features).
I would use Facebook's new SDK because your project will be able to use all the new features. Your project will also last longer (in case Facebook changes its API and doesn't update the old SDKs, which is unlikely to happen in near future but don't expect your project to last longer than 4 years!).
A reason for not updating would be if your web server doesn't support PHP 5.4+ but you should rather update/change your web hoster.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering this same question, as my Facebook App had stopped working recently, and you may find you can get away with just updating the `fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt` file from the latest version SDK but not the rest of the SDK files, in the instance that you are having any CURL SSL errors. That's what was preventing my App from working properly, and updating the certificate to the more recent one in the latest SDK is what worked for me just now.

But I agree with @Matt3o12 that you're better off starting any new projects with the latest version.